# Boot Camp Assistant 6 does not allow drive-less install

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I tried installing Windows via Boot Camp Assistant 6 on OS X 10.11 on a MacBookPro Retina 15" (Late 2013, Model No MacBookPro11,3) but I don't get the new drive-less install option where the Assistant creates the OSXRESERVED partition and uses that as install source for Windows.

According to [Twocanoes](http://blog.twocanoes.com/post/130203487014/apple-boot-camp-no-longer-requires-usb-flash-drive?utm_source=loopinsight.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20loopinsight%2FKqJb%20(The%20Loop)&utm_content=FeedBurner) (who found out about this) my machine is compatible.

Is there a workaround to this? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: The web page your referenced does not show your model as being compatible. Generally, Macs started using USB drives for Windows installs beginning with the 2012 models. Starting around the 2015 model year, the new Macs could not longer install Windows using the legacy BIOS/MBR boot method. Since the web page you referenced is for modern EFI/GPT Windows installs, this is probably when they went to this new way of installing.

Comment: @DavidAnderson true, its possible that only the 2015+ models support this install method. Knowing Apple however, e.g. what they do with their "MacbookAir only" Superdrive where all you have to do is add 2 lines of text to a plist to get it to work on any Macbook I am certain that there is a workaround for this.  Boot Camps Info.plist also had such workarounds for devices which initially only supported Disc installs to support USB installs, so I'm searching for something along those lines..

Comment: While it is true that you can edit the info.plist file to allow the Boot Camp Assistant to create the USB installer, the same Mac will not boot from the created installer. There may be an exception here and there, but this is true for the most part. The general rule is that if your Mac came with an optical drive, then you can not boot the Windows installer using a USB port.

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to force the Boot Camp Assistant to preform this type of install on your model Mac? Or, are you look for a way to install without USB or DVD and without the Boot Camp Assistant?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I am mainly looking for a way to force BCA to do the drive less install.